# Which fish species is it?

Tags: species-identification, ichthyology

Today we found this kind of fish on the shore of Baltic Sea near Gdansk (PL). It is a very thin "fish" with some kind of a needle in place of nose. It was about 5 cm long and very lively. What is the name of the species?

[image]

PS. Kids caught it into a bucket just to take a pic - we released the creature just after the photo session :)

Comment: I am super super sure it is a straightnose pipefish which is usually found in the baltic

Comment: Yes, but are such long needle noses common in that species?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a pipefish, possibly [a straightnose pipefish.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straightnose_pipefish?wprov=sfsi1)

[See also.](http://www.fishbase.se/summary/1331) But the size suggests a juvenile?

Comment: Thank you @alan-boyd for your answer. The one you suggest has however much shorter "needle" than the one on my photo, at least compared to the photos over the web. Could it be _Syngnathus typhle_ perhaps?

Comment: Agreed, that looks like a possible match, but size is still a problem. Mine was a quick-and-dirty answer - I assumed that a Baltic pipefish expert would be along to clarify. Without a better image you may never know exactly what species it was.

Comment: Hi. I also found _Microphis brachyurus aculeatus_ on the web, which looks at most similar to the one we found. However, according to the sources, it does not appear in Baltic Sea , only in Senegal, Angola, etc...